# Position of the button in custom list item

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am trying to [![make the button ][1]][1] at the corner of the listitem but its not working
this is what i tried

```
Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Colors.black12,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 100,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      child: Image.network(_items[index]['product_img']),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(_items[index]['product_name']),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text('M.R.P:  ₹  ' +
                                _items[index]['product_price']),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  child: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                    child: ElevatedButton(
                                      child: Text("Add +"),
                                      onPressed: () =>
                                          print("it's pressed"),
                                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                        primary: Colors.red,
                                        onPrimary: Colors.white,
                                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
```

tried to set the size also but that is also not working , In one of the sugession i was told to put crossAxis also that i tried and still not working
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ1hY.png

Comment: Before your button place `Spacer()` as Row`s child, this will do the trick

Comment: tried but the button is not visible then

Comment: remove `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` from row.